# Remove Number Of Pagination

Tags: pagination

When I visit to my category page (example page 6) then my pagination is like this ->

[Prev][1][…][5][6][7][…][12][Next]

In this case, we are in the [6] button now. So, [5] button is same function with [Prev] button, and [7] button is same function with [Next] button, right?

How to remove the left and right number (in this case [5] and [7]) button? No matter if I can remove it via .php file or custom css.

Regards

Comment: This is an issue with either your theme or a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the function which outputs pagination. It could look like this:

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size' => 2,
    'prev_text' => __( 'Prev', 'textdomain' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Next', 'textdomain' ),
) ); ?>
```

You need to change `mid_size` parameter. This parameter determines how many page numbers to display to either side of the current page. 
So try change to
`'mid_size' => 1`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination

Comment: I added mid_size parameter to archive, index, and search. It works. Thanks.

Comment: Great, glad it helped! When you get the answer that solves your problem you should mark the answer accepted. See here [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)